# Найти определенный substring, используя MySQL REGEXP INST

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

Утро доброе!

Имеется: бд MySQL 8. с таблицей Friends и полем about

- Нужно: вытащить название города, тип - substring city (пример: .city/n.moscow (точки - это пробелы, /n - это перенос строки)) из колонки about
- Инфа в ячейке about хаотично разбросана
- В ячейке после слова city лежит нужная инфа (название города). Её нужно перенести в новую колонку city.

Как получить название города из текста ячейки?

Пример table:

```
id | about      | city 
-------------------
   | Name/n     | 
   |  .Aleks/n  | 
   |  .City/n   | 
   |  .Moscow/n | 
   |  .Phone/n  | 
1  |  .324231/n | null
   |  .Social/n | 
   |  /n        |
   |  ./n       | 
   |  .vkid/n   | 
   |   .123/n   | 
-------------------
   | Name/n     | 
   |  .Vasil/n  | 
   |  .Phone/n  | 
   |  .311312/n | 
   |  .City /n  | 
2  |  .Novsib/n | null
   |  .Social/n | 
   |  /n        |
   |  ./n       | 
   |  .vkid/n   | 
   |   .122/n   |
   -------------------
   | Name/n     | 
   |  .Aleks/n  | 
   |  .Social/n | 
   |  /n        |
   |  ./n       | 
3  |  .vkid/n   | 
   |   .341/n   | null
   |  .City/n   | 
   |  .Moscow/n | 
   |  .Phone/n  | 
   |  .324231/n |
```

Необходимо вынести название города из ячейки about в city и получить таблицу такого вида:

```
id | about      | city 
-------------------
   | Name/n     | 
   |  .Aleks/n  | 
   |  .City/n   | 
   |  .Moscow/n | 
   |  .Phone/n  | 
1  |  .324231/n | Moscow
   |  .Social/n | 
   |  /n        |
   |  ./n       | 
   |  .vkid/n   | 
   |   .123/n   | 
-------------------
   | Name/n     | 
   |  .Vasil/n  | 
   |  .Phone/n  | 
   |  .311312/n | 
   |  .City /n  | 
2  |  .Novsib/n | Novsib
   |  .Social/n | 
   |  /n        |
   |  ./n       | 
   |  .vkid/n   | 
   |   .122/n   |
   -------------------
   | Name/n     | 
   |  .Aleks/n  | 
   |  .Social/n | 
   |  /n        |
   |  ./n       | 
3  |  .vkid/n   | 
   |   .341/n   | Moscow
   |  .City/n   | 
   |  .Moscow/n | 
   |  .Phone/n  | 
   |  .324231/n |
```

Comment: Добавьте в текст вопроса: DDL имеющихся таблиц, пример их наполнения (скриптом) и желаемый ответ на именно этих данных. Лучше в форме fiddle. И укажите точную версию сервера.